# How to use Ionic UI components in Ionic v4 --type=angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

The ionic components like `ion-button` , `ion-input` are not working in ionic type=angular. 
For example using `<button ion-button>Click<button>` does not work.
How can I use them?

Comment: ionic 4 have new changes, you should refer to updated documents: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the Ionic documentation to see how to use the components:

For example `ion-button`:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Usage:

```
<ion-button>Default</ion-button>
```